# PowerBI - Convert Kusto Dashboards to PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

I have been given the task to convert Kusto (ADX) dashboards to Power BI. I did some research (Query to Power BI from Kusto) but I would like to take suggestions on what is the best way to covert Kusto Queries to Power BI Dashboard.

Should I try the 1) Import or 2) Direct Query option in Power BI
Thanks for suggestions and request to share any reference links or use cases, Best practices .

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to "convert" dashboards from ADX dashboards to PBI dashboards.
You need to create the dashboards in PBI. I would not recommend using the query to PBI option, rather us the native connector ADX has in PBI.
For best practices and general information you can start with these links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/power-bi-connector
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/power-bi-best-practices